# Display only one time a value from column's table

Tags: php

After a SQL request, I have a table like this (way bigger but here is an example) :

```
host__id | Host   | service__id |  service_name
================================================
     001 | Host 1 |     100     |  Service 1
     001 | Host 1 |     101     |  Service 2
     002 | Host 2 |     102     |  Service 3
     002 | Host 2 |     103     |  Service 4
     002 | Host 2 |     104     |  Service 5
```

I would like to display each host with his services. 
For example : Host1:Service1,Service2 ; Host2:Service3,Service4,Service5.

I can't make it to work because the same host will display several time and I don't want this.

Also, the table change all the time. This means I don't know before how much hosts/services will be display.

Any ideas how I can do this ? Thank you !

EDIT : This is my SQL request to get records from that table :

```
    $displayhost = "SELECT T1.display_name as host_name,T1.host_object_id, T2.display_name as service_name,T2.service_object_id
                    FROM 
                    nagios_hosts T1
                    INNER JOIN nagios_services T2
                    ON T1.host_object_id = T2.host_object_id
                    WHERE T2.service_object_id IN (".$ids.") ";

$selecthost = $db->prepare($displayhost);
$selecthost->execute([$ids]);
$hostdisplay = $selecthost->fetchall();

foreach ($hostdisplay as $display){                             
      //the code I struggle with
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@xarj: You need to modify your query until unless this'll not work perfectly. Just add order by clause for your host name i.e host 1, host 2.

I hope this'll help:

```
$str = "";

foreach ($hostdisplay as $key => $display) {

    $str .= $display["service_name"];

    if ($key < count($hostdisplay) - 1 && $display["host_name"] == $hostdisplay[$key + 1]["host_name"]) {
        $str .= ",";
    } else {

         echo $hostdisplay[$key]["host_name"] . ":" . $str;
         echo "<br>";
         $str = "";
     }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you it works perfectly ! But there is a few things I don't understand. ".="  : what is the purpose of the '.' ?  And why "$key => $display" ?

Comment: ".="  this is just for the concatenation, it ll append the text to $str i.e like  $str = $str .

Comment: "$key => $display" to get keys of array for more into xfer : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php